# Toggle visibility on load if checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, toggle

Tried to find similar answers, but did not find one with this exact problem. Sorry if I missed one in my search.

I have this code

```
    jQuery(function (jQuery){
      jQuery("#discount_ongoing").click(enable_date);
    });

    function enable_date() {
    jQuery('#discount_start').toggle();
    jQuery('#discount_end').toggle();
    }
```

It simply toggles the visibility of two calendars. As it is, it just turns the calendars on and off when the checkbox is clicked, which is fine until I save the state of the checkbox, then when I load the page with it already checked, obviously the toggle will do me no good because it works in the opposite direction.

How do I check the state of the checkbox so the calendars start off in the correct state when the page loads? Or, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function (jQuery){
    jQuery("#discount_ongoing").click(enable_date).triggerHandler('click');
});

function enable_date() {
    jQuery('#discount_start, #discount_end')[this.checked ? 'show' : 'hide']();
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Cb7Y7/)

Comment: Changing the first function fixed it. But is there any particular reason to rewrite the enable_date function? It works fine with the toggle. Just trying to learn.

Comment: @SpectralEdge it done so that the visibility state of the fields are in sync with the state of the checkbox not according to how many times the method is called

Comment: It is doing the opposite of what it should do though. It hides when it should show and vice versa.

Comment: @SpectralEdge just switch the positions of `show` and `hide` like `[this.checked ? 'hide' : 'show']`